# Deleting reparse point

Tags: windows-xp, reparsepoint

I created a reparse point using the junction.exe utility. Now when I try deleting it using the "-d" switch, it returns an error and claims that access is denied. Checking the Properties for the junction folder, there is a greyed-out check mark at "Read Only," which keeps on returning after I try to reverse that attribute. Help please!!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got around the problem by creating an empty folder, and redirecting the reparse point to that folder. Once that was done, I was able to delete it.